# How to get data from RouteComponentProps

Tags: reactjs

I want to use information from `import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router-dom";`. I know that this module can provide information about our URL, but i can't set it. How to get data about the URL in my React component?

```js
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';
const App = () => {
  console.log(here i want to get information about my URL);
  return (
    <div className="main">
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: you need the full url like `http://yoururl.com/home` or you need only `/home`? 2nd one  you can get it by `this.props.location.pathname`

Comment: @tareq aziz, did use `RouteComponentProps `?

Comment: I used react-router-dom but not RouteComponentProps

Comment: do you know how to use `RouteComponentProps `?

Comment: Basically I used `BrowserRouter` and `Route` of `react-router-dom`

Comment: You can see this `https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start` and see the 1st example and then put `props.location.pathname` into any functional component you can get the url, if you want to use other than `RouteComponentProps`

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you can use it like this:

```
const App = ({ match }: RouteComponentProps<any>) => {
```

Assuming your routing is something like this:

Given that the RouteComponentProps is defined as this:

```
export interface RouteComponentProps<Params extends { [K in keyof Params]?: string } = {}, C extends StaticContext = StaticContext, S = H.LocationState> {
  history: H.History;
  location: H.Location<S>;
  match: match<Params>;
  staticContext?: C;
}
```

You can then understand that the match I've extracted holds the url data for you to examine. So assuming your url is http://foo/your-component/bar

```
this.props: all properties including routing-related
this.props.match.params.param1: prints 'bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use react hooks, if you are using in functional components.

Code will be as below

```
import { useParams} from "react-router"; 
    import { useLocation} from "react-router";
    const App = () => {
       let location = useLocation();
        console.log(location);  // for url location info
      let params = useParams();
       console.log(params );  // for params information
      return (
        <div className="main">
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default App;
```